k8s nginx ingress proxy_redirect
I'm trying to achieve this simple configuration on a kubernetes nginx ingress controler:
  location /path1/ {
      proxy_pass             http://server-1:8000/;
      proxy_redirect       http://server-1:8000/ /path1/;
  }

  location /path2/ {
      proxy_pass             http://server-2:8000/;
      proxy_redirect       http://server-2:8000/ /path2/;
  }

  location / {
      proxy_pass             http://server-auth:8000;
  }

The idea is to redirect /pathX/ to the / of different servers (server-X) and the root path to server-auth
To do this, I ended up with two ingresses for the same host name (www.mysite.com):

One for the server-x redirections with the rewrite-target annotations:

    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
(...)
    - host: "www.mysite.com"
      http:
        - path: /path1(/|$)(.*)
          pathType: ImplementationSpecific
          backend:
            service:
              name: server-1
              port:
                number: 8000
        - path: /path2(/|$)(.*)
          pathType: ImplementationSpecific
          backend:
            service:
              name: server-2
              port:
                number: 8000


And another one just for the authenticator without the rewrite-target annotations:

    - host: "www.mysite.com"
      http:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: server-auth
              port:
                number: 8000

This is because the annotations can't be dedicated to one path (or I don't know how to proceed)
I feel like that's a lot of code for such a small configuration, so I'd like to know if there's a simpler or more elegant way to do it ?
Thank you
Julien
